# How to change dropdown menu color in double commander in ubuntu 18.04 Ambiance theme?

Tags: 18.04, gnome, themes, gui

How can I change color for double commander's menu? The text color is too close to the background color.

[image: dropdown menu color]

Comment: How did you install Double Commander? Did you install `doublecmd-gtk`? I get decent contrast with Ambiance.

Comment: Yes, I did install doublecmd-gtk